# Limiting Data With Lucene.NET

Tags: full-text-search, azure-sql-database, lucene.net

We are using Sql Server 2012 Full-Text indexing, however we would like to move our database to Sql Azure.  Using the migration tool it is telling us that Full-Text indexing is not compatible with Sql Azure (even v12 which is in preview does not support it so it doesn't look like they intend to support it).

Because of this we are looking at alternatives and the best I have found so far is using Lucene.NET with AzureDirectory (https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com).  This will allow us to store the index in blob storage and cache it locally on the file system of the VMs which host the web sites (also in Azure).

The issue we have is that the data we intend to index is items such as news stories which are not visible to all users because of a publishing model we have which limits items to be visible to just a subset of the users.  With Full-Text indexing when searching for a news story we can limit the data for the using searching using a simply join on what is visible to them, however with Lucene we will not be able to do this.

The idea we have come up with is to take news stories in the index with a collection of UserIds that are allowed to view that news story, I am afraid I am very new to Lucene and I cannot work out the best way to do this, we are adding the index for a news story like so:

```
  document.Add(new Field("Title",
               news.Title,
               Field.Store.YES,
               Field.Index.ANALYZED,
               Field.TermVector.NO));
  document.Add(new Field("Content",
               news.Content,
               Field.Store.YES,
               Field.Index.ANALYZED,
               Field.TermVector.NO));
```

However if we have a collection of userIds defined as

```
IEnumerable<int>
```

How could we add these to the news story index and then search on them effectively for a given user id.  Additionally what will the performance hit be if we are adding 100s or 1000s of UserIds against a lucene document.  Is there a better way to go than down this road as this might be a terrible idea (probably is a terrible idea)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ran into that problem while migrating to Azure and have ended up with that same permissions model. Since your userIds are integers and won't have special characters then you can rely on many of the Lucene(.net) analyzers like StandardAnalyzer and WhitespaceAnalyzer to split a list of IDs into terms as long as you input a string. Just separate each ID with a space or comma depending on what the Analyzer will split on.

You should be able to do something simple like this to index the IDs...

```
IEnumerable<int> userIds = new int[] { 123, 456, 789 };

document.Add(new Field("AllowedUserIDs",
 String.Join(" ", userIds), 
 Field.Store.NO, 
 Field.Index.ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
```

Then just make sure to query with a TermQuery to match whole terms(IDs). Something like...

```
int currentUserID = 123;
string queryString = "airplane";

BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("AllowedUserIDs", currentUserID.ToString())), Occur.MUST);
query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Title", queryString)), Occur.SHOULD);
query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Content", queryString)), Occur.SHOULD);
```

I can't speak very specifically to the performance concerns but we have a few hundred IDs in our lists and it hasn't seemed to impact the query times since we added it. Really it's no different than searching on a few hundred or few thousand word news article.